# ¿ Cómo podía crear en añadir equipos una opción de borrado del diccionario?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo creadas varias clases más abajo de la que podes observar. Son :
mostrar_equipo(self)
borrar_equipo(self)
Está ultima es la que no sé como hacer para que pueda borrarme un registro introduciendo en la opción Borrar de la clase añadir equipos...

```py
    class Liga():
    
        primera = {}
        segunda = {}
        segundaB = {}
        pr=[]
    
        def __init__(self, nombre_liga, numero_equipos):
            self.nombre = nombre_liga
            self.equipos = numero_equipos
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return "El nombre de las ligas son:  {}\nLa forman {} equipos\n".format(self.nombre, self.equipos)
    
        def añadir_equipos(self, id, nombre_equipo):
            p= str(input("¿Quieres añadir un equipo?:\n1.Si\n2.No\nNOTA:Si no desea implementar más datos, escriba: salir\nEscriba aquí su respuesta ==> "))
            if p == "si" or p== "si":
                c= str(input("\n¿Categoria del equipo que quieres incluir?: \n1. Primera\n2. Segunda\n3. SegundaB\n ==>"))
                if c == "1":
                    for i in range(20):
                        id= str(input("ID del equipo: "))
                        if id == "salir":
                            self.mostrar_equipo()
                            print("Gracias por usar nuestro programa")
                            exit()
                        if id == "borrar":
                            id = input("nombre")
                            for id in self.primera.key():
                                del self.primera[id]
```

Comment: no entiendo muy bien tu lógica del añadir_equipos. En esta función creas equipos y a la vez y puedes borrarlos ?

Comment: Sé que va encontra de toda lógica, y quizás luego sacaría fuera de esa función y bucle la posibilidad de borrar. ¿Pero si quisiera hacerlo, habría alguna forma?

Comment: a ver si clarificamos tu pregunta, mas alla de que tu codigo no parece muy logico. Lo que preguntas es como se borra por completo un diccionario, como se borra un elemento de un diccionario o que cosa?

Comment: Cómo se podría borrar un registro que ya se efectuó en el diccionario. Es decir, agrego dos equipos mediante ( añadir_equipos). En un momento dado, en medio de ir añadiendo equipos, decido borrar uno del diccionario. Ejemplo el primero que añadir, entonces escribo en terminal borrar, pongo ideas o nombre ( me es indiferente) y borró ese registro del diccionario

Comment: Bueno para borrar un elemento de un diccionario puedes hacerlo a través de su clave con el metodo pop(), por ejempo `primera.pop(key)` o a través de su valor con el metodo remove `primera.remove(valor)`. En el ciclo for tienes mal el metodo key(), es self.primera.keys(), de esa forma obtienes la clave y luego con del self.primera[id] tambien puedes eliminar un elemento, pero con los metodos que te mencioné no haria falta usar el for, no se si esto responde a tu pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias soyunework me ha funcionado con self.primera.pop(id)